# Force subclass to call super on overriden method

Tags: typescript

When extending classes, sometimes we forget to call the super class implementation in a method that was already implemented.

Is there any way to prevent this by throwing an error or something when a method is being overriden and not calling super?

---

**Example**

```
class MainClass implements OnInit
{
    ngOnInit() {
        // base implementation
    }
}

class InnerClass extends MainClass
{
    ngOnInit() {
        super.ngOnInit(); // ---> throw error if didn't call this line
        // additional implementation
    }    
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you don't want to call the parent's method. How would you implement that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular, so I'm guessing this isn't possible, but I normally avoid overriding methods when I want to call the base implementation, with the exception of `constructor` since there typescript will throw an error [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Root%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20Root%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: @TamasHegedus Good question... In my particular case the method needs to be called for sure, but yes, it's not like that in all cases. Perhaps that's why this wasn't implemented (if). Probably forcing to insert an "override" keyword would be a more generic solution for this, at least it would be enough to warn that the method exists in the super class. But that was already asked long time ago and doesn't seem to have been implemented yet: [Issue #2000](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2000)

Comment: 4.3 adds the `override` modifier to ensure the method is overridden, at least you'll know then that the `super` method should exist and may/must be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interesting discussion about it on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21388), the word `concrete` was proposed, but no, currently it's not supported in TS. You got to use some workarounds for that (also listed on that page).

Comment: One year later, not much has changed on that side