# force calling the super destructor using symbols

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use symbols as return type so the derived class requires to call the parent in order to get the original `Symbol()` that only the parent knows

```
export type Ctx = CanvasRenderingContext2D;
export type GameContext = { [x : string] : unknown };

export interface IEntity {
    x : number;
    y : number;
    death : boolean;
}

abstract class Entity implements IEntity {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    death : boolean = false;

    private readonly secret : symbol;
    constructor( x : number, y : number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.secret = Symbol();
    }
    destructor() : Entity['secret'] {
        return this.secret
    }
}
class SubEntity extends Entity {
    constructor() {
        super(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    }

    destructor() {
        return Symbol();
        //return super.destructor();
    }
}
```

What i've been trying to do is force the derived class to call the parent destructor in order to get the `secret` return value.
The problem comes when it allows the derived class to return any `Symbol()` and not only the one generated in the `Entity` constructor

i'm aware there is a *similar* question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213234/force-subclass-to-call-super-on-overriden-method) that links to a github discussion about new keywords. However, the aproximation i use is different.

**edit**: i forgot to mention that this question refers to all kind of functions in a class and not only for a `destructor`, since a `destructor` function is just a regular function for JS (and TS) and has no special connotation like in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21388#issuecomment-360214959) is a way to achieve the same result i was looking for but using an `Anonymous Class` as return type to the parent `destructor` instead of a `Symbol()`.

I strongly beliefe that this the optimal way to achieve forcing the call of the `super.destructor` inside the subclass `destructor`.